# How can you tell if samples are from the same population

Tags: self-study, anova, statistical-significance, variance

Given the 7 different samples with mean and variance for each group. What can I use to tell if these samples from the same population with 0.05 and 0.01 significance level?

```
Sample   Mean   Variance   
A        50      5
B        47      4
C        52      5
D        51      6
E        49      5
F        52      4
G        49      6
```

Based on the give data, I calculated F statistics of value 53.72.

Given the the F data, how would you conclude that these samples are drawn from the same population? Is the conclusion the same for the both for 0.05 and 0.01 levels of significant?

I am trying to follow this example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#One-way_ANOVA_example

but the problem is that I don't have the individual observation to calculate the within-group sum squares. I only have the mean, variance and sample size(10) data. Any ideas how I could approach this?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Please add self-study tag an tell us what you tried in that case.

Comment: @Glen_b, I updated the post.